# Find $Z=X+Y$ given $f(x,y) = 2(x+y)$ for $0\leq x \leq y \leq 0$ using transformation method.

Tags: probability, statistics, random-variables

> Given the joint pdf
>   $$f(x,y) =
> \begin{cases}
> 2(x+y) & 0 \leq x \leq y \leq 1, \\
> 0      & \text{otherwise}.
> \end{cases}
> $$
>   Use the cdf transformation to find pdf for $Z = X+Y$.

**The following is what I did, but I think they are totally wrong. I tried many times but couldn't get a reasonable solution.**

So I came up with let $$V = X, Z = X+Y.$$
Thus $$X = V, Y = Z-V.$$
And $$J = \begin{vmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ -1 & 1 \end{vmatrix} = 1.$$
Therefore $$ f_{V,Z}(v,z) = f_{X,Y}(v,z-v)\cdot|J| = 2z.$$
In addition, $$ 0 \leq x \leq y \leq 1 \Rightarrow 0 \leq v \leq z-v \leq 1 \Rightarrow 0 \leq v \leq z/2. $$
Then calculate the marginal $$f_Z(z) = \int_0^{z/2} 2z dv = z^2.$$

Comment: Note: $0\le v\le z-v\le 1 \;\implies\; \max(0, z-1)\leq v\leq z/2$ for $0\leq z\leq 2$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The triangles in the images show the areas in $xy$ and $vz$ planes where $f(x,y)$ is not identically zero.

[image]

$$f_Z(z)=\begin{cases}
\int_0^{z\over2} 2zdv=z^2,& 0\le z<1\\
\int_{z-1}^{z\over2}2zdv=z(2-z),& 1<z\le2
\end{cases}$$

Answer (score 1):

Mostly correct, save that $0\le v\le z-v\le 1 \;\implies\; \max(0, z-1)\le v\le z/2, 0\le z\le 2$. (Because $z-v\le 1 \implies z-1\le v$ .)

$$(v,z)\in (0;z/2)\times(0;1)\cup(z-1; z/2)\times[1;2)$$

So the marginal is $$\begin{align}f_Z(z) & = \int_{\max(0;z-1)}^{z/2} 2z\operatorname d v\;\mathbf 1_{z\in (0;2)} \\[2ex] & = z^2 \mathbf 1_{z\in(0;1)}+ (2z-z^2)\mathbf 1_{z\in [1;2)}\end{align}$$